# Is there any benefit to using the Remote Development (WSL) feature for XHTML ebook development?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, xhtml, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL (Ubuntu) on my Windows 10 machine just because there are some Linux command line tools for developing ebooks specifically designed and needed by [Standard Ebooks](https://standardebooks.org/). I'm only working with **XHTML** and **CSS** files. Is there any benefit to me in using the **remote development (WSL)** extension in **VS Code**? I can already access my files just fine with Windows Explorer. I'm not sure what the benefit of this feature is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [extensions marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) states:

> **Why Remote – WSL in VS Code?**
>
> While you can edit files in Linux using Windows-based tools, you can’t easily run or debug on Windows: you'd have to install all the same tools on Windows as you did on Linux, defeating the purpose of having an isolated Linux environment. You could view files from your \wsl$\ share, but you wouldn't have access to features such as autocomplete, debugging, or linting.
>
> With VS Code and the Remote - WSL extension combined, VS Code’s UI runs on Windows, and all your commands, extensions, and even the terminal, run on Linux. You get the full VS Code experience, including autocomplete and debugging, powered by the tools and compilers installed on Linux.

You can summarize and say that some benefits you gain are:

- Ability to use whatever Linux compilers and tool features available
- The ability to use Visual Studio Code features for developing, such as autocomplete and debugging but with said Linux features previously mentioned

Comment: Thanks. I had read that description, but I was and still am somewhat confused. I turned the **Remote** feature off, and my files are stored in \wsl$\, but the autocomplete features still function. I don't know what they mean by **autocomplete** since the editor continues to do this regardless.

Comment: @ConsciousClay I think when they say autocomplete, they mean _Visual Studio Codes autocomplete_ i.e. the IDE's.